# How to play video using Mediaplayer framework in ios?

Tags: ios, video, media-player

here i want to play a youtube video using mediaplayer framework.For this i follow this process,
1)I am adding mediaplayer framework.
2)I am importing #import  header file
3)I implemented code by using google

But it shows thread ,

Can any one tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this out:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-playing-video-with-the-mediaplayer-framework/
as well check this thread :
[how to play video from url using mpplayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938621/how-to-play-video-from-url-using-mpplayer)

Answer (score 1):

Please try thie one .. i think this one may your help.

```
- (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender
{    
    NSURL *videosURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YourVideoURL"];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:videosURL];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayController.view];

    [moviePlayController prepareToPlay];
    moviePlayController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    moviePlayController.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [moviePlayController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

    if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
        [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```